# Cannot include files from another folder

Tags: php, include, pear

I have current directory structure `htdocs/mvc2/` which includes app and public folders.

If i run bootstrap.php `http://localhost/mvc2/app/core/bootstrap.php` with require_once `'../config/config.php'` it's included, works fine.

If i try to include bootstrap.php in my `http://localhost/mvc2/public/index.php`
I'm getting the following errors:

> Warning: require_once(../config/config.php): failed to open stream: No
>   such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\mvc2\app\core\bootstrap.php
>   on line 2
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   '../config/config.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mvc2\app\core\bootstrap.php on line 2

I can include bootstrap.php file in my index.php if i comment out all the includes in bootstrap.php file though:|.

Im using windows7 with xampp.
I have tried changing `php.ini` file as suggested by others having the same problem to no avail. It's currently:

```
; UNIX: "/path1:/path2"
include_path=C:\xampp\php\PEAR
; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
;include_path = ".;C:\xampp\php\pear"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open

> C:\xampp\htdocs\mvc2\app\core\bootstrap.php

and edit this line

```
require_once('../config/config.php')
```

give the full path of this file **config.php**

you can use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/YOUR_INCLUDEABLE_FILE_NAME';`

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is The document root directory under which the current script is executing, as defined in the server's configuration file.

your server will return `C:\xampp\htdocs`  by using  `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`.

Comment: how you edit this line require_once('../config/config.php') give me the path of this '../config/config.php' file

Comment: require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/mvc2/config/config.php';            or require_once 'C:/xampp/htdocs/mvc2/config/config.php'      both doesn't work :/

Comment: require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/mvc2/config/config.php');

Comment: unfortunetly it's the same.

Comment: after pasting require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/mvc2/config/config.php'); this which error you got can you plz comment it

Comment: Warning: require_once(C:/xampp/htdocs/mvc2/config/config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\mvc2\app\core\bootstrap.php on line 3

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:/xampp/htdocs/mvc2/config/config.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\mvc2\app\core\bootstrap.php on line 3

Comment: check C:/xampp/htdocs/mvc2/config/config.php has existed in folder

Comment: Oh it works ;), Thank you a lot, it really was giving me headache                 forgot to put app folder after mvc/app/config/config.php.                                         Will that mean I need to include all my files with full url from now on?

Comment: always double check your file before including .thanks

Answer (score 0):

hard coding the full path works.
Tried using $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/YOUR_INCLUDEABLE_FILE_NAME' in win10 the DOCUMENT_ROOT is showing "/" instead of "\". It fails.